# Add metadata to blob

Tags: node.js, angular, web-mediarecorder, openai-whisper

Using the [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) object, I get the input of an user mic.
Everytime I receive the data, I send it to the backend in order to process it. I do not wait for the audio file to be complete as the data needs to be treated in real time.

I use the received audio to send it to the [Whisper API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/speech-to-text). The first chunk of data is well processed. However the following are not. From my research, this is because MediaRecoder sets the metadata only on the first Blob. When I try to read the files, I can only open the first one while the others are corrupted.

I tried to convert the blob using node-lame (needs an external program), wavefile (buffer is not supported).

I can think of two solution :

1. Add metadata to each blob. I looked into [link](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/extendable-media-recorder/issues/638), but I still don't know how to manually set a header.
2. Find a clean way to use MediaRecorder.start and MediaRecorder.stop in order to not loose any data.

Here is my current code :

speech-to-text.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SpeechService } from '../service/speech.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-speech-to-text',
  templateUrl: './speech-to-text.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./speech-to-text.component.scss'],
})
export class SpeechToTextComponent implements OnInit {
  mediaRecorder!: MediaRecorder;

  constructor(private speechService: SpeechService) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
    this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

    this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', (event) => {
      this.speechService
        .sendAudioBlob(new Blob([event.data], { type: 'audio/mp3' }))
        .then((result) => console.log(result));
    });
  }

  record() {
    this.mediaRecorder.start(1000);
  }

  stop() {
    this.mediaRecorder.stop();
  }
}
```

speech.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AppHttpClientService } from './app-http-client/app-http-client.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SpeechService {
  constructor(private httpService: AppHttpClientService) {}

  async sendAudioBlob(blob: Blob) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('blob', blob);
    const result = await this.httpService.post('speeches/text', formData);
    return result;
  }
}
```

speeches.service.js (backend)

```js
const openai = require('../models/openai');
const fs = require('fs');
const formidable = require('formidable');
const { MODEL_NAME } = require('./speech.constants');

const fileDirectory = `${__dirname}/../../../uploads`;

const SpeechesService = {
  speechToText: async (req) => {
    const fileName = `${Date.now()}.mp3`;

    const form = new formidable.Formidable({
      uploadDir: fileDirectory,
      filename: () => fileName,
    });

    await form.parse(req);
    const resp = await openai
      .createTranscription(fs.createReadStream(`${fileDirectory}/${fileName}`), MODEL_NAME)
      .catch();

    SpeechesService.deleteAudio(fileName);
    return resp.data;
  },

  deleteAudio: async (fileName) => fs.unlink(`${fileDirectory}/${fileName}`, () => {}),
};

module.exports = SpeechesService;
```